# How to get Google Workspace user subscriptions using Google API

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I can obtain the information about each user for the given Google Workspace organization using the following [endpoint](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list):

> GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users

However, the licensing information is missed in the response. How can I get the list of all active subscriptions for the given Google Workspace user?